# WordPress: Can't use multiple query->set for pre_get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code that used to be restrict posts in WordPress admin panel by author and custom field. I mean, I have about 20 authors and they can add their own posts, and when writing new posts there is one **Custom Field** that current author can set that custom field and let others to see that post.

My authors have custom role with custom abilities (Due to some required usage) and by default they can see each other posts in posts list. I used the code to restrict authors to see only their posts.

Then I decided to use one custom field, so when one author use in their own post, that post should be available to other authors.

Is this case I had to use multiple `$query->set` But doesn't work! Look at this function code:

```
function pposts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $pagenow,$post_type;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    if('edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin ) {
        return $query;
    }
    
    // This is how should handle Movie custom post types for showing
    // Posts to authors. All of authors should see their own posts and
    // Those posts that have custom field 'parbandeh_masool' if value is = 2
    // $post_type == 'parvandeh' &&
    elseif ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && in_array( 'invoicer', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

        $query->set('author', $user_id );
        
        // Additionally, check for a custom field 'parbandeh_masool'
        // If set to 2, allow the user to see those posts
        $query->set('meta_key', 'parbandeh_masool');
        $query->set('meta_value', 2);
        
    }

    
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'pposts_for_current_author');
```

At the second part (elseif), I intend to restrict authors to see only their own posts and all posts that have specific custom field when value is equal something. **My problem is exactly in this section!** When I use 3 of `query->set` together

```
$query->set('author', $user_ID );
$query->set('meta_key', 'parbandeh_masool');
$query->set('meta_value', 2);
```

**Nothing show to authors!**

When I only use `$query->set('author', $user_ID );` it will only show their own posts to authors.

When I only use `$query->set('meta_key', 'parbandeh_masool'); $query->set('meta_value', 2);` without `$query->set('author', $user_ID );`, it will show only posts that have specific custom field!

But it can't handle this two together!

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your issue but you have at least one problem with your code. On the first `elseif` condition you have `&& !current_user_can( 'delete_parvandehs', $user_id )`, however `$user_id` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere before this check. Same thing applies to the second `elseif` condition.

Comment: @cabrerahector Thanks, applied your suggested changes but actually doesn't affect to the main problem. query sets couldn't work together.

Comment: Well, I _did_ say that these issues may not be related to your problem. Still, your updated code has a new problem now: you declared `$user_id` at the top of your function, and then you're trying to use `$user_ID` below. [Variable names in PHP are *case sensitive*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Comment: And you're registering `$user_ID` as a global variable. Not sure if said global variable actually exists (at least I don't think it's created by WordPress, see [Global Variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables)) unless you created it yourself somewhere outside of your `pposts_for_current_author()` function?

Comment: @cabrerahector Thanks again mate, I just updated the code again and doesn't work again. See the new code. The real problem is those 3 `$query->set` can't work together. `user_ID` was created in another place, I changed the code to make sure everything is in the code itself. But still `$query->set`s doesn't work. this is main problem. Please take a look for those `$query->set`'s problem